# Liquid forloop and arrays

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have master tag list and a product tag list. I would like to check the master tag list against product tag list and eliminate the tags from the master list that are not present in the product tag list.

```
{% assign masterTagList = 'DROP GTA, DROP VAN, DEL GTA, DEL VAN, BIG PRODUCT, SHIPS NATIONALLY, DROP SHIP' | split: ','%}

{% assign productsAssembledTagList = '' %}
  
  {% for item in cart.items %}
        {% for productTag in item.product.tags %}
            {% assign productsAssembledTagList = productsAssembledTagList | append: ', ' | append: productTag %}
        {% endfor%}
  {% endfor%}

{% assign productsAssembledTagList = productsAssembledTagList  | remove_first: ',' | split: ',' | uniq %}


{% for eachTag in productsAssembledTagList %}
    
      {% if masterTagList contains eachtag %}
          <p>Master Contains</p>
      {% else %}
          <p>Master does not contain</p>
      {% endif%}
    
  {% endfor%}
```

Comment: Would this not be a ton easier just using Javascript? I see your attempt to coax it out with Liquid, but Liquid is just so clunky for these kinds of exercises.

Answer (score 0):

```
{% assign notCommonTags = "" %}
{% assign commonTags = "" %}
{% for eachMasterTag in masterTags %}
      {% if productTags contains eachMasterTag %}
          {% assign CommonTags = CommonTags | append: ", " | append: eachMasterTag %}
      {% else %}
          {% assign notCommonTags = notCommonTags | append: ", " | append: eachMasterTag %}
      {% endif%}
{% endfor%}
```